# Proper subsets with closest sum

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you have sets $A$ and $B$ of positive reals, with $sum(A) = sum(B)$. Is there an efficient algorithm to find proper subsets $A_1$ of $A$ and $B_1$ of $B$ such that $abs(sum(A_1) - sum(B_1))$ is minimal? This seems similar to knapsack problems, so my guess is that there is nothing really efficient, but maybe there are algorithms that quickly provide for $A_1$ and $B_1$ with low sum difference.  What to you think?

EDIT: Consider only the case when $A$ and $B$ are finite and $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: When you type $sum(A)$, you want to say $sum(A)$ is the sum of all elements of set A?

Comment: @DiegoMath yes, exactly that.

Comment: So, $A$ and $B$ should be finite sets in this case.

Comment: I think the problem makes sense as well for numerable sets whose sum is bounded. But for the moment, yes, let us consider them finite.

Comment: Note that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, then is done, it is just take $A_1=B_1=A\cap B$.

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately the intersection is empty for the cases that matter in my problem.

Comment: I suspect this is NP-complete even if restricted to sets of positive integers. I would look in the book by Garey & Johnson, or maybe just type $$\rm subset\ sum\ problem$$ into Google.

Comment: Thank you, Gerry. Yes, if even finding a subset of a given set with a specific sum is NP-complete, this must be as well. Nevertheless I was hoping maybe a not-too-bad heuristics was known for approximate solutions. But I guess even that is hard.